# Cannot Install cuda 5 samples on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I install cuda 5, while I cannot install its samples since

```
Missing required library libglut.so
```

I look for the anwsers, someone say

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

for x64 architectures. But how to do it for x32 architectures?

Comment: find the libglut.so file on your system and link it to /usr/lib directory

Answer (score 4):

To make sure you have GLUT installed you should try

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```

that will install GLUT in Ubuntu 12.04. If it's not installed it will install it, otherwise it'll tell you that

```
freeglut3-dev is already the newest version.
```

If after that it still doesn't work you can link it from here: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 (which is the [location of the library in Ubuntu 12.04 32bit](http://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/ubuntu-updates-main-i386/freeglut3_2.6.0-1ubuntu3_i386.deb.html)) with something like

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so
```

Comment: On my system (Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit), it is at "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3", so I got it working with this command:
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglut.so.3 /usr/lib/libglut.so

Answer (score 2):

I've found something like this:

> If OpenGL and/or GLUT is not installed on your system, you can install both with:
>
> `yum install freeglut-devel`
>
> which should install all the dependent packages, including OpenGL itself.

Instead of `yum` try `sudo aptitude` or `sudo apt-get` but it depends on you linux distribution.