# CUDA/OpenCL on ubuntu that is installed on a USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, usb, opencl, virtualbox

I've been trying to get CUDA/OpenCL running on my windows system. I can get them working (I have a compatible video card and I've installed the CUDA toolkit) but compiling the sample programs is proving to be very annoying and has just led to more errors. So, I want to try installing CUDA on ubuntu. Forgive the following noob questions.

I want to keep windows as my main drive for gaming etc. I don't have a second hard drive (I could buy one but not if I can avoid it!) so my options are:

1) install ubuntu on virtualbox - I've read that CUDA won't work using this method?

2) install ubuntu onto a flash drive permanently - would this work? can persistent USB OS's  utilise the PC's graphics card?

3) dual boot both OS's to my existing hard drive - I assume this would work and be stable? What kind of risk does it pose to my existing data (I've got a lot of mp3's etc and nowhere to back them up)?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Open the ubuntu installation CD in windows, you can find the `setup.exe` to achieve dual boot without a separate disk partition.

Comment: I'm trying the wubi installer, which I suppose does the same thing :)

Comment: Yes, it's wubi. I forgot the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To virtual box I can't say anything how it works with cuda.

If you install ubuntu on a flashdrive you can use [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). It creates a "live" cd on the flash drive, but you can also add a seperate memory which stores everything you change on the live system (It's called like "Spaces used to preserve files... (Ubuntu only)" ). This will include all manual installed programs and drivers. So it will act like a real installed ubuntu.

Also you can install ubuntu direct to your flashdrive. Therefore you have to install grub in the mbr of the flashdrive. Additional it's better to edit the fstab, too and write the uuid of the partitions instead of the original entry.

The probably best way is to make a dual boot system. Ubuntu have a comfortable installer which gives you the option to install it besides your existing windows system. But it will need free space on your hard disk.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! I didn't realise installing ubuntu on an existing windows drive was quite so easy, thanks to wubi. I shall report back if I get CUDA working.

Comment: It could happen that you aren't able to install the sdk samples. Often the problem is a non-linked freeglut lib, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081854/cannot-install-cuda-5-samples-on-ubuntu-12-04). I had the problem on every pc i've installed cuda under ubuntu.

Comment: CUDA won't be able to find any usable GPUs if installed inside a virtualbox machine.

Comment: CUDA is up and running fine, and ubuntu was very easy to install with wubi. I couldn't recommend the process more for getting CUDA working easily! I followed the [sn0v guide](http://sn0v.wordpress.com/2012/12/07/installing-cuda-5-on-ubuntu-12-04/), but I didn't do the 'purge nvidia*' step as that ruined my desktop the first time I tried the install.